# Variable static en Macro de Excel VB

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo pendiente un proyecto y desconozco mucho del lenguaje Visual Basic en Macros.
La idea es que copiara una tabla consecutivamente en intervalos al presionar un botón. Lo de copiar ya está echo, el detalle es que **busco crear una variable estática que se inicialice UNA VEZ en 7 (contador), y cada que presione el botón al contador se le sumará 20** y luego copiará y pegará las celdas. La forma en que lo hago me marca error y la forma que hayé me marca error de ejecución.
He hecho un archivo a parte para practicar esto pero da el mismo resultado.
Quisiera que me apoyaran diciéndome que está mal de la sintaxis.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es por donde esta declarada, coloca tu código

```
Static R As Integer
if (R = 0) then i = 7
```

Coloca esto dentro de tu modulo.

Comment: Vaya, es cierto, la respuesta era tan sencilla y batallé varias horas por eso.
Muchas gracias. ;)